# drools plugin in Eclipse Sample.drl shows errors

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

I am new with Drools. I use drools plugin (6.4.0.Final) in Eclipse Neon. I followed the wizard to create a drools project with some example files. After the steps were done, Eclipse highlighted errors at the two rules in the Sample.drl file. Here is one of the errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
com.sample.DroolsTest.Message cannot be resolved to a type
org.drools.core.util.bitmask.AllSetBitMask cannot be resolved to a type
Only a type can be imported. com.sample.DroolsTest.Message resolves to a package
org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle cannot be resolved to a type
KnowledgeHelper cannot be resolved to a type
Only a type can be imported. org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper resolves to a package
Message.GOODBYE cannot be resolved to a type
org.kie.api.runtime.rule.RuleContext cannot be resolved to a type
java.lang.Exception cannot be resolved to a type
```

When I ran DroolsTest.java, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=Sample.drl, line=15, column=0
text=Rule Compilation error Only a type can be imported.            com.sample.DroolsTest.Message resolves to a package
Only a type can be imported. org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper resolves to a package
KnowledgeHelper cannot be resolved to a type
org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle cannot be resolved to a type
java.lang.Exception cannot be resolved to a type
org.kie.api.runtime.rule.RuleContext cannot be resolved to a type], Message [id=2, level=ERROR, path=Sample.drl, line=5, column=0
text=Rule Compilation error Only a type can be imported.     com.sample.DroolsTest.Message resolves to a package
Only a type can be imported. org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper resolves to a package
KnowledgeHelper cannot be resolved to a type
com.sample.DroolsTest.Message cannot be resolved to a type
org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle cannot be resolved to a type
org.kie.api.runtime.rule.FactHandle cannot be resolved to a type
java.lang.Exception cannot be resolved to a type
org.kie.api.runtime.rule.RuleContext cannot be resolved to a type
Message.GOODBYE cannot be resolved to a type
org.drools.core.util.bitmask.AllSetBitMask cannot be resolved to a type
com.sample.DroolsTest.Message cannot be resolved to a type]]
at  org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:450)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:604)
at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:575)
```

It seems like an library path issue. Any helps are appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like your import statements are incorrect. `com.sample.DroolsTest.Message resolves to a package` means you need to `import com.sample.DroolsTest.Message.*` instead?

Comment: Sample.drl was generated after the wizard. I did not change anything. After changing the import as suggested, I got one more error: BuildError: Unable to resolve ObjectType 'Message'

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding **dialect "mvel"** at the two rules in Sample.drl. 

Is it a bug in the drools wizard that dialect is missing in the examples? or It supposes to work without dialect?

Thanks.

Comment: I degraded Eclipse to Mars2, and reinstalled the plugin. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in either Neon or drools plugin, it's fixed in drools plugin (6.5.0.Final) based on this site: [jboss-issue-description](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-1250)

But since I don't find 6.5.0.Final version released, you can fix this by **degrade eclipse to Mars**